# How to nest JPanels within GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I want to nest JPanels within JPanels in a GridBagLayout. Here is a picture of the problem I am having:
[image]

As you can tell, nesting components within a JPanel thats inside a GridBagLayout causes the JPanel to inflate in size. This is a problem since I cannot add components to JPanels without them changing in size.

Here is the code:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GridBagDemo {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Grid grid = new Grid();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100,100, 500, 500);
        frame.add(grid);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
class Grid extends JPanel {

    public Grid () {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        GridBagLayout bagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout(bagLayout);

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        JPanel navBar = new JPanel();
        navBar.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("hello world");
        navBar.add(label);
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.gridwidth = 2;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.05;
        add(navBar, gc);

        JPanel toolBar = new JPanel();
        toolBar.setBackground(Color.blue);
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.weightx = 0.3;
        gc.weighty = 0.3;
        add(toolBar, gc);
        //Second row
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.weightx = 0.15;
        gc.weighty = 0.3;
        add(content, gc);

        JPanel navBarChild = new JPanel();
        navBarChild.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.weightx = 0.3;
        gc.weighty = 0.3;
        add(navBarChild, gc);
        //Third row
        JPanel bottomLeft = new JPanel();
        bottomLeft.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.3;
        add(bottomLeft, gc);

        JPanel bottomRight = new JPanel();
        bottomRight.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.weightx = 0.3;
        gc.weighty = 0.3;
        add(bottomRight, gc);
    }
}
```

My preferred behavior would be the ability to add components to a nested JPanel without the JPanel increasing in size.

I have researched this topic on google for some time and most results are not relevant to my issue. There are two SO answers that are somewhat related, but not actually about the same issue.

Comment: There are at least two calculations going on.  There is the `GridBagLayout` trying to provide divide up the available size of the parent container to the components, based on `weightx`/`weighty` constraints and there is also `GridBagLayout` trying to honour the `preferred` and `minimum` size properties.  Since you've not provided sizing hints for `preferred` or `minimum` sizes, `GridBagLayout` is left with the available space of the parent container, which you've restricted to `500x500`

Comment: BUT, this isn't actually the size of the content area.  The content area is been sized to an error less then `500x500`, because the frame decorations take up space WITHIN the frame itself.

Comment: *"This is a problem since I cannot add components to JPanels without them changing in size.*" - That would kind of be the point, as the size needed by the component will be different on different systems

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't quite understand your explanation of how gridbaglayout allocates space. You mean I need to use preferred size for the JFrame? Or set minimum size for all of the JPanels?

Comment: Stop trying to set the size the frame - use `pack`, then you need to define sizing hints for the component which don't already generate there own